# How to Parse JSON having data types with values?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have an issue with JSON data. 
In my Json it is having data types with values. not sure how to parse.

ex:

```
 {
"id": "123456",
"name": {
    "firstName": {
        "String": "Nathon"
    },
    ,
    "lastName": {
        "String": "Jason"
    }
 }.
```

Please help on this

```
public String map(ObjectNode jsonNode) throws Exception {
                return  value.get("id");
            }
```

I tried with the above sample code , but i am able to parse only "id"

Comment: can you show how you are parsing ?

Comment: show the code and still this will be String "string" not datatype

Comment: public String map(ObjectNode jsonNode) throws Exception {
                return  value.get("id");
            }

Comment: I am able to parse only id.

Comment: what do you want this method `map` to return? @Nathon

Comment: Its returned id value.

Comment: what do you want? what is your question? @Nathon

Comment: How to parse this type of JSON. I am not able to get a name node in FirstName and lastName?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188930/discussion-between-deadpool-and-nathon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all you don't have to mention the data types in order to parse a JSON appropriately, just create a POJO class matching the structure of JSON then use GSON to parse JSON into a java class

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Jackson2` then get then `name` as `JsonNode`

```
JsonNode nameNode = value.path("name");
```

And then again get the `firstName` and `lastName` as `JsonNode`

```
JsonNode firstName = nameNode.path("firstName");
JsonNode lastName = nameNode.path("lastName");
```

From `JsonNode firstName` and `JsonNode lirstName` get the string value

```
String name1 = firstName.path("string").asText();
String name2 = lastName.path("string").asText();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but its getting data type with a value. Like  { "String": "Nathon"}.  I need only value, not with String

Comment: no problem still it is a string you get the value like this `firstName.path("String").asText();` @Nathon

Answer (score 0):

When your json is deserialized into `ObjectNode` then it is actually represented internally as a map key/value in which value can itself be again a map as is in your case. Visually if you look at it, it would be something like this.
So you would need to follow this structure using get(fieldName) to get the value OR an `ObjectNode`  if it is nested . Remember if the return value is `ObjectNode` then simply printing it would just return the json fragment it represents, so you would need to call again '`get(fieldName)`' on that object.

[image]